# elrte : dialog is not a function error

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

When I click add image or add flash or add table button, especially when I click buttons that open a dialog box, I'm getting this error.

What is the problem do you think?

```
in firefox

    Error: jQuery("<div />").addClass(this.opts.class).dialog is not a function
    source file: elrte/js/elrte.min.js
    Line: 3

 in chrome

    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' elrte/js/elrte.min.js:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is exactly as the error messages explain. Your jQuery object doesn't have a method named `dialog`.

jQuery doesn't have a `dialog` method by default, and apparently one hasn't been provided.

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com) does have one, so you'd need to load that if that's the one you're intending to use.

[Here's the demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for jQueryUI dialogs.

Answer (score -1):

You should add jQuery UI CSS Framework (jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css)

Open dialogs in new Elrte 1.3 not working with old version jquery UI 1.7! 
Last version 1.3 working just jquery UI > 1.8.3